# How can i place a relative button at a fixed place right of the brwowser window?

Tags: html, css

I have a relative positioned button with a fixed left value on my page which keeps its location when scrolling. The only problem i got is when the browser window width gets changed or when the client device has a small screen. In this case the button is outside the visible screen.

I think it would be nice to define that this button should always be 50px from the browser window right limit. How can i achieve this?

**Update**: I used `float: right` already, which is almost what i want, but the button is still to close to the browser window border (is over the vertical scollbar). To place it 50px moreto the left would solve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
div#button {
    position:fixed; /* or position:absolute; */
    right:50px;
    bottom:10px; /* or another value */
}
```

Comment: +1 stupid me, should have thought of position:fixed myself, thanks

Comment: because IDs are unique you can say just `#button` instead of `div#button`

Comment: @11684 it depends on the weight you want to assign to the selector. However in general it's not the same thing ... but it is the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

use `float:right` and `margin-right:50px`

Answer (score 2):

use `margin-right` and `float:right;`

```
#button{margin-right:20px;float:right;}
```